# How am I supposed to beat Egypt without being able to plant the green plants?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I'm playing tutorial mode but after I get teleported to Egypt, I lose the ability to plant the Peashooters. I don't want to buy any power-ups or special items to beat these levels.

[image]

I've reinstalled the game twice already but I still can't plant the Peashooters. I used the Walnuts and Potato Mines to beat Day 1 but it was very hard and I don't want to play the whole game that way.

What am I missing?

Comment: looks like a bug to me, you should have the basic pea shooter

Comment: the green plants are called **peashooters** :D

Comment: definitely a bug

Answer (score 4):

So I just went through the start of the game on a new profile, and indeed you should have pea shooters:

[image]

(Ignore the extra plants, they rolled over from my main profile)

The first thing I'd recommend is to delete and recreate your profile on the home screen. If you opted to skip the tutorial the first time, try going through it. If you went through it the first time, try skipping it.

If after deleting and recreating your profile you still don't have the pea shooter, complete day 2 which will unlock the cabbage-pult, which is nearly identical to the peashooter in terms of cost and damage output. As you progress, you'll unlock plants that are vastly superior to the pea shooter anyway.